# BlackBerry TripleDESEncryption output convert to String

Tags: blackberry, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a String using TripleDESEncryption and followed this example I found on the internet (link: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/crypto/doc-files/CryptoTest.html#sampleMD5Digest):

```
// sampleTripleDESEncryption
private static int sampleTripleDESEncryption( byte[] secretKey, byte[] plainText, byte[] cipherText ) throws CryptoTokenException, CryptoUnsupportedOperationException
{
    // Create a new Triple-DES key based on the 24 bytes in the secretKey array
    TripleDESKey key = new TripleDESKey( secretKey );

    // Create a new instance of the Triple-DES encryptor engine, passing in the newly 
    // created key
    TripleDESEncryptorEngine engine = new TripleDESEncryptorEngine( key );

    // Encrypt one block (8 bytes) of plainText into cipherText
    engine.encrypt( plainText, 0, cipherText, 0 );

    // Return the block size of the engine
    return engine.getBlockLength();
}
```

However, I want to convert the encrypted data to String. I'm not sure if the cipherText variable is the one to be converted. Any help? How am I going to convert it?

Comment: That's correct. Chiper text keeps encrypted data now

Comment: What do you mean it is correct? The method returns an int. I want to convert the encrypted data to human-readable form. Do you know how to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just don't expect that result will be returned through parameter.

So first of all allocate enough buffer in `chiperText`. Call the method and you will have result in `chiperText` buffer with returned length (return value).